# ASN.1: ENUMERATED vs INTEGER

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, x.509, asn1

From the X.509 specs:

```
   CRLReason ::= ENUMERATED {
        unspecified             (0),
        keyCompromise           (1),
        cACompromise            (2),
        affiliationChanged      (3),
        superseded              (4),
        cessationOfOperation    (5),
        certificateHold         (6),
             -- value 7 is not used
        removeFromCRL           (8),
        privilegeWithdrawn      (9),
        aACompromise           (10) }
```

...and...

```
Version  ::=  INTEGER  {  v1(0), v2(1), v3(2)  }
```

Why isn't Version an ENUMERATED type?  And similarly, why isn't CRLReason an INTEGER?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ENUMERATED` and `INTEGER` are almost identical (they just use distinct tags). The generic idea is that `ENUMERATED` is for a choice within a bounded set of possible values, whereas `INTEGER` is for values which could, at least theoretically, raise indefinitely.

Here, the use of `ENUMERATED` for `CRLReasons` is a *hint* which says that "there shall be no other reason in the future", whereas there may well be other protocol versions (possibly many others).

Now that's just a declaration of intent, which will not be enforced in any way. Remember that the justification of most of ASN.1 is: "it looked like a good idea at that time". Do not try to read too much in it. After all, ASN.1 succeeded in defining, well into the 1980s, a format for dates which has only two digits for the year -- a glaring [Y2K issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem), which did not deter the standardization committee... so just accept the `ENUMERATED`/`INTEGER` duality as one of the numerous quirks of ASN.1 (it's not the worse).

Comment: Paul's answer is more correct in that they serve different purposes.  The fact that ASN.1 supports named integers in the first place is a quirk; it would have been better for all enumerated values (e.g. named constants as found in cpp `#define`) to be represented as ENUMERATED.  X.509's use of INTEGER for Version is another quirk that would have been avoided had ASN.1 not enabled it.

ENUMERATED can be extended in the future - the lack of a `...` is the hint that it won't be.  See Larmouth, section 12.4: https://books.google.com/books?id=F-UJp_esh9QC&pg=PA208.

Answer (score 6):

ENUMERATED and INTEGER serve different purposes.  ENUMERATED is for creating a list of named items while INTEGER is for carrying numbers.  The fact that the type notation seems somewhat similar does not make them identical.  For ENUMERATED, the only values permitted are those named in the list.  For INTEGER, the named list is just a set of useful labels for specific numbers, and does not limit what values are permitted for the INTEGER type.

I can only assume that CRLReason was made ENUMERATED because there is a closed set of values while Version was made an INTEGER to leave the number of future versions open ended.

Feel free to try some of these specifications at http://asn1-playground.oss.com, which is an online ASN.1 compiler and encoder/decoder that supports not only BER and DER, but also PER, XER and CER.  You will be able to see that differences between ENUMERATED and INTEGER seem more significant for other encoding rules (such as PER and XER) than they seem for BER and DER.